# Refresh wallpaper Deepin Linux

Tags: debian, desktop, desktop-customization, gconf

I'm trying to change my wallpaper on Deepin Linux (the X server is Deepin Desktop Manager (dde)) with the command line. I can do it with the command `gsettings set com.deepin.dde.appearance background-uris` but I need to wait for a user logout/system reboot for the new wallpaper to be displayed.

How could I solve my problem — is there a command which reloads the wallpaper or something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this schema with dconf to switch my wallpaper on deepin

```
dconf write /com/deepin/wrap/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri "'/path/to/image'"
```

You can alternatively use this one (which I find more convenient because there is no need of quotation mark in the syntax)

```
gsettings set com.deepin.wrap.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/image
```